# Using Python, how can I multiply all matching integers in a list and then add the remaining integers

Tags: python, algorithm, logic, algebra

I am working to recreate a dice game known as Knucklebones in Python as a fun personal project.

For the game logic, I need to multiply all matching values in a list and then add the remaining values.

**Example 1:**

```
numbers = [3, 3, 2]
```

This list should multiply both 3 and 3 together then add 2 for a total of 11.

**Example 2:**

```
numbers2 = [4, 4, 4]
```

This list should multiply 4 by 4 by 4 for a total of 64

**Example 3:**

```
numbers3 = [2, 4, 6]
```

Nothing should be multiplied in this list. All numbers should be added for a total of 12.

Can someone please help me with the logic surrounding this?

Comment: Does  your list always contain 3 items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work

I will advise to use a modified Counter from the built in module collections.

The counter by default will count just the entries of all the list
them as it works similar to a dictionary is fairly simple to multiply all entries and sum them up

here you have more info:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

https://realpython.com/python-counter/

```py
from collections import Counter

class MyCounter(Counter):
    def __ini__(*arg, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
        
    def sum_entries(self):
        total = 0
        for key, val in self.items():
            total += key**val
        return total
    
out = MyCounter([3, 3, 2])
output = out.sum_entries()
```

output

```
out = MyCounter([3, 3, 2])
output = out.sum_entries()
print(output)
```

```
11
```

```
out = MyCounter([4, 4, 4])
output = out.sum_entries()
print(output)
```

```
64
```

```
out = MyCounter([2, 4, 6])
output = out.sum_entries()
print(output)
```

```
12
```

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments
To avoid having a class if it seems to complicated

```py
from collections import Counter

out = Counter([3, 3, 2])
total = 0
for key, val in out.items():
    total += key**val
```

Comment: Ooh, this is clever. But you should explain this, not just post code.

Comment: What is `out.items()`? Does it depends on the external/global `out`?

Comment: @cards no it does not depend it was my mistake, thanks for the comment

Comment: This is magic! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in approach. Used `dict.fromkeys` to initialize to zero the counter (and remove duplicates). Then fix the frequency of the outcomes with the *loop* and apply the "Knucklebones" rule.

```
numbers = [3, 3, 2]

d = dict.fromkeys(numbers, 0)
for n in numbers:
    d[n] += 1

res = sum(k**frequency for k, frequency in d.items())
print(res)
```